# How to calculate MAX not NULL in table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

How can I get that MAX 3 months with not NULL?

As result I need UserId, UserAgreementId and MAX Not NULL And Group BY UserId

| month | Id | UserId | UserAgreementId | SubsriptionDate | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 12 | 222 | 33333 | 2020-02-02 00:00:00.000 | 40000 |
| 3 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | 13 | 222 | 33333 | 2020-04-03 00:00:00.000 | 5000 |
| 5 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 6 | 15 | 222 | 33333 | 2020-06-04 00:00:00.000 | 7000 |
| 7 | 16 | 222 | 33333 | 2020-07-02 00:00:00.000 | 8000 |
| 8 | 17 | 222 | 33333 | 2020-08-09 00:00:00.000 | 4000 |
| 9 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 10 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 11 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 12 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

As Result must be smth like this

| UserId | UserAgreementId | MAX |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 222 | 33333 | 3 |

Table AgreementId have SubsriptionDate in rows and I need to calculate period with max not empty Amount

| UserAgreementId | SubsriptionDate | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 33333 | 2020-02-02 00:00:00.000 | 40000 |
| 33333 | 2020-04-03 00:00:00.000 | 5000 |
| 33333 | 2020-06-04 00:00:00.000 | 7000 |
| 33333 | 2020-07-02 00:00:00.000 | 8000 |
| 33333 | 2020-08-09 00:00:00.000 | 4000 |

Comment: Is that sample data or the expected result? We need both anyway.

Comment: I create a tmp table with 12 months, and left join a table with data joined by month(SubsriptionDate)

Comment: Why 3? What is that a max of?

Comment: Max of not NULL one by one

Comment: What would be the result of user 444 had 2 consecutive months, or 3 consecutive months?

Comment: Months will be unique for each UserId. Month can be not present and than it will be NULL in joined result

Comment: Max excluding nulls for your purpose is easy: `MAX(IFNULL(column, 0))`, however, the query required to do what your asking is overly complex and more suitable to being done when processing the data in a programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for is too complex for a query - it will take a long time to run.

For example, I've put together a draft below that just about gets the longest duration for each user, yet it references the same table 5 times.

This is barely readible, convuluted, and will tax the server more than you want.

Instead, fetch the records and process them in a more suitable programming language.

```sql
SELECT t.user_id, MAX(t.monthsTotal - s.monthsTotal + 1) AS longestDuration
FROM (SELECT a.*, YEAR(a.subscriptionDate) * 12 + a.month AS monthsTotal
     FROM table_name) as t
INNER JOIN (SELECT a.*, YEAR(a.subscriptionDate) * 12 + a.month AS monthsTotal
    FROM table_name AS a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name AS preceeding
        ON a.user_id = preceeding.user_id
        AND YEAR(a.subscriptionDate) * 12 + a.month = YEAR(preceeding.subscriptionDate) * 12 + preceeding.month + 1
    WHERE preceedingMonth.id IS NULL) AS s
    ON t.user_id = s.user_id
    AND t.monthsTotal >= s.monthsTotal
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT a.*, YEAR(a.subscriptionDate) * 12 + a.month AS monthsTotal
    FROM table_name AS a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name AS preceeding
        ON a.user_id = preceeding.user_id
        AND YEAR(a.subscriptionDate) * 12 + a.month = YEAR(preceeding.subscriptionDate) * 12 + preceeding.month + 1
    WHERE preceedingMonth.id IS NULL) AS dummy
    ON t.user_id = dummy.user_id
    AND dummy.monthsTotal > s.monthsTotal
    AND t.monthsTotal > dummy.monthsTotal
WHERE dummy.id IS NULL
GROUP BY t.user_id
```

Comment: thank you for you time. You are right. Will use some another way

Comment: @Miscellaneous If I'm right, perhaps marking as the correct answer?